# Programatically set maxLength on web form based on XSD schema

Tags: asp.net, webforms, xsd, maxlength

I have an ASP.NET web form that includes text boxes similar to this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="someElement" runat="server" XPath="(some XPath)" />
```

My form uses an XSD schema that includes code similar to this:

```
<xs:element name="someElement" type="myForm:Limit150" minOccurs="0" />
  :
<!-- (code left out for brevity/clarity) -->
  :
<xs:simpleType name="Limit150">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1" />
        <xs:maxLength value="150" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This form has a large number of textboxes, and they all do not have the same maxLength requirements.

I'm finding out that when the form is submitted, it checks against the schema and returns error messages that are not user-friendly (unfortunately, it isn't my code, so I can't just change it).  I think the best way to go would be to set my maxLength in the TextBox fields.

However, I *really* do NOT want to hardcode my maxLength values in my web form (as follows):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="someElement" runat="server" XPath="(some XPath)" maxLength="150" />
```

I would much rather get the values that are defined in the schema and define them programatically on my web form.  I'm thinking that, on my FormLoad event, I can grab the values and set the TextBox attributes on the code-behind.

What I *don't* know, however, is how to get the values from the schema.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  How would I go about it?

Note: my code-behind language is VB.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I might have found something helpful [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157325/how-to-find-restriction-values-in-a-simple-xsd-element-with-c-sharp) . . .

Comment: . . . and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04x694fe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).